# Project Curve on Surface

Tags: bezier-curves

I would like to know how to project a bezier curve onto an extruded bezier curve.
as an example in Autodesk Maya is:
[Create a curve-on-surface](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Modeling/files/GUID-F023FD2B-9EFC-429D-809E-6AF6B298548F-htm.html)

Is there a way to do this in Blender 2.79b or the soon to be released 2.8?
I know this can be done on a polygon surface but, I don't want to do it on a polygon surface.

Comment: do you have a picture of what you want?

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/50560#50560) answer your question? Also, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen when looking for the answer, it is **no**. The Blender Foundation is not focused on improving NURBS or Bezier surface modeling tools at this time.

the Knife Project tool is a Polygon tool. The Knive Project tool does not allow for one to project a curve onto a NURBS or Bezier surface in Blender 2.79 or 2.80.

Answer (score 0):

In blender 2.79

Convert the Extruded Curve into mesh using Alt C

Then select the Curve and the Converted Mesh and Switch to Edit Mode to project the Curve to it.

In Edit Mode, on the Tool Shelf, select Knife Project

The Curve will be projected onto the surface