# How can you cut shapes out of an object with other objects?

Tags: modeling, workflow, knife-tool

I know this has been asked before but I seem to be struggling to use either the knife project tool or merging meshes and then separating out sections to cut pieces in a mesh. This is probably due to some fundamental misunderstanding but there must be an easier way to do this rather than making 1000 edge loops to line up with the curves.

---

Here's the sheet with pieces overlayed:
[image]

When I consolidate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> then separate <kbd>P</kbd> you can see that the piece gets separated but the original base sheet remains untouched.

If anyone has any advice that would be much appreciated. I was hoping the knife project tool would be the easier way but whenever I use it only part of the piece gets cut not the entire thing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example

Comment: Unfortunately no dice, the extrude through the object and intersect method is the closest but the curved section doesn't get added to the base sheet so it ends up missing!

Comment: Aha so I think an issue with that particular piece is that the curved vertices aren't connected through the base sheet. However when I try to connect them by selecting then pressing F either only the top and bottom points connect or they don't line up with each other. Is there an easy way to connect the vertices without having to select them all one by one?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would usually do this is to make the cutting objects 3D and then join them with the object to be cut then use Intersect (Boolean) face tool.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like this approach and it seems the easiest but unfortunately the curved section on the piece shown above is not connected across vertices and for some reason the base sheet then doesn't recognize the curve even if stretched through the sheet, I guess because there aren't any edges along there that are intersecting so I'd love to know if there's an easier way to connect those vertices rather than selecting each one by one?

Comment: @KaphaSound Can you share your .blend file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com