# How can I get the outline of a shadow with Freestyle?

Tags: shadows, freestyle, svg

For a vector illustration project, I am looking for a way to extract the shadows of objects in Freestyle. Currently I am only able to export the object itself (with *Freestyle Edge Marks* and the *Freestyle SVG Export* add-on):

[image: Left: monkey rendered in blender with a drop shadow. Right: the exported .svg only contains the object, and not the shadow]

How can I reveal the contour of the shadow with Freestyle?

Comment: Freestyle only exports hard geometry. Shadows don't have a coherent outline that can be unequivocally traceable. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for your comment. So you suggest to mimic the shadow with the *Knife Project* tool, so as to give the shadow a "substance" of sorts?

Comment: That might work. Though it involves a certain amount of manual work. Maybe you can do it non destructively with modifiers like *Shrinkwrap* perhaps

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you could try the following:

- Import your rendered PNG into [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org)
- use the "bucket fill"-Tool on the shadow, this will rather neatly trace the contour of the shadow (as long as the color is somewhat uniform)
- Set line and fill of the traced area as you like
- Import the Freestyle-generated SVG on top and move/scale as needed
- Delete the PNG

This should give you a pretty good vector image for further usage

Comment: @haarigertroll thanks for this workaround. I will try this.