# How to make a template

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, geometry, template

im a absolute beginner using blender and hope someone can help me.
I work as a prosthetist and wanted to create a template for some foam which i have to glue into a orthesis.

i do have a stl of the orthesis but it has over 300k polygones which is to high to use the unwrap feature.

is there a quick and easy way to get the shape of the orthesis as a simple cutout?

if someone could help me it would be awsome for me and my patient as well.

best wishes
timo

Comment: You probably want to look into the [boolean modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html?highlight=boolean).

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and may be put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Obviously only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe in detail what the issue is, supported by [reference images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for review.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example/77281#77281