# How to cut a plane in a shape of another planar mesh?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a terrain-looking plane made with Geometry Nodes (gray in the image below) and I would like to cut out a "meadow" on it (yellow in the image below) to assign different materials to the two parts.

[image: Two meshes in Blender]

I've created the "meadow" mesh outside of Geometry Nodes by cutting a plane in the shape I like. From there, I've brought this mesh into the geometry nodes and extruded it to intersect with the "landscape". With the Mesh Boolean node I am able to select the "outside" part of the landscape, but can't find a way to select the part inside the "meadow" extrusion.

[image: Extruded meadow intersecting landscape]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example/77281#77281

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Are you sure that this is a duplicate? The question was about [tag:geometry-nodes] (and would need more details to allow an answer).

Comment: Indeed, good catch, sorry about that. Missed the part that it was about geometry nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get both the inner mesh and the outer mesh, and have the inner mesh follow the contour of the terrain, you would (unfortunately) have to use two `Mesh Boolean` nodes:

[image]

One node intersects with *Difference* the inner part from the outer, and the other node intersects the inner mesh with the terrain, so that a mesh is created that corresponds to the surface of the terrain.

But to also remove the side parts created by the extrusion, you would have to capture a boolean value in the geometry of the meadow mesh before this action, and use this selection afterwards to remove the excess faces.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

you can just use mesh boolean with intersect and difference:

[image]