# Convert or merge elements to workable objects

Tags: modifiers, objects

I have no prior experience with blender and objects.
I have a osm "object" with a bunch of elements I would like to convert in to a object or something I can modify and reshape. Im trying to merge it with the plane I have under it.
Is there a way to do this? Any help would be amazing!

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/how-can-i-view-the-perspective-projection-of-an-arbitraryy-shape-onto-the-plane/